# Find Gravity in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer

I wants Find gravity in objective c, I am using Accelerometer  in my project. but I not got any good tutorial on Google for find gravity, So i need help

I wants to move small red circle inside Gravity Meter, shown in image attached.

I am currently using accelerometer can i find gravity using accelerometer.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

 ...............

  labelX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"X: ", acceleration.x];
  labelY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"Y: ", acceleration.y];
  labelZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"Z: ", acceleration.z];  
![enter image description here][1]}
```

Thanks

[image]m.png

Comment: `stringWithFormat:@"%@%f", @"X: ", acceleration.x];`- why so? Why not `stringWithFormat:@"X: %f", acceleration.x];`?

Comment: I just copy paste code from the internet, thanks , can you help me in find gravity?

Comment: @MSB `redDotView.origin = CGPointMake(x * screen_width, y * screen_height);` or some variation thereof should be enough. Also, don't "copy-paste code from the Internet", that's bad.

Comment: @H2CO3 i wants calculate gravity (G value) in float, can you help me?

Comment: @MSB `const float g = 9.806; /* in m/s^2 */` since it's (almost) constant. Or do you want to calculate the acceleration of the device?

Comment: @H2CO3 please have a look on that app, https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/vidometer/id552124663?mt=8 , yes in this app when I up and down my device the G changes 0.1 to 0.5 , I think it calculate the force, please suggest me what to do

Comment: @H2CO3 and please look at this youTube video exactly same http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk2mlqYiryA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at that app (videometer) it seems you're looking for G-force being exerted. G-force is NOT gravity - it is an outside mechanical force (user swinging the device, etc) specifically defined as NOT being from earth's gravity. This is important because on an iPhone or any other accelerometer-enabled device, it reports all 0 when there's no motion. If it was reporting gravity, any readings would constantly be reporting motion in the Y/downward axis (earth pulling you down).

You're looking for G-force which means you need:

1. The direction of the motion
2. The force of the motion

Check out Apple's documentation of the [UIAcceleration object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006901) - you will get the direction based on which variables are changing - `x`, `y`, `z`.  The value of those variables gives you a force (with 1.0 approximating g which is 9.8m/s2 - earth gravity).  How you display that data on a graph depends on you - you can store a history of the acceleration events and then animate them, and reset the point to the middle when acceleration stops (the UIAccelerometer shared object will start reporting 0 values when acceleration stops).